# ¿Porque una muestra el valor de la operación y la otra muestra el objeto lambda?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda

estoy siguiendo este ejemplo:

```
> def prueba(op, x, y):
>     return{
>         "add": lambda: x + y,
>         "sub": lambda: x - y,
>         "mul": lambda: x * y,
>         "div": lambda: x / y,
>     }.get(op, lambda: None)() 
>print(prueba("mul",3,5))
```

Y efectivamente el resultado en pantalla es el deseado, "15".

Sin embargo si ejecuto este código, que según yo es lo mismo que devuelve la función:

```
print(lambda: 3 * 5())
```

El resultado el ago totalmente diferente:

```
<function <lambda> at 0x000001EF1EF2BCA0>
```

¿A que se debe esto?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bienvenido Fernando c:

## Explicación

El error se debe a que Python cree que los parentesis al final del lambda (`()`) son parte del propio lambda, no un intento de llamarlo.
El código que muestras (`print(lambda: 3 * 5())`) tiene un equivalente en forma de función así:

```
def lambda():
    return 3*5()

print(lambda)
```

## Solución

Para solucionar este "malentendido", tenemos que indicarle a Python donde el lambda termina encerrandolo entre parentesis de este modo:

```
print((lambda: 3 * 5)())
```